# How to display as a table combined output of a program and a file and watch it in 1 sec

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program **isig**, that displays 18 rows of data, want to combine it with text file **info1.txt** that also has 18 rows of additional data into a table view and watch it in 1sec interval.

My command to display the table is:

```
pr -m -t <(isig 4001+18) info1.txt
```

And if I add watch:

```
watch -n 1 'pr -m -t <(isig 4001+18) info1.txt'
```

I get:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Is there a way to achieve this in bash command line

Comment: what is output of typing `echo $SHELL`. Note that your error message says `sh`, and `bash`. How to fix that will be a game of 20 Qs that I can't spare time on. This sort of Q gets asked all the time, maybe searching for `[linux] [bash] command not found` will get you close. Good luck.

Comment: echo $SHELL is /bin/bash

Comment: watch -n 1 'bash -c "pr -m -t <(isig 4001+18) info1.txt"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process substitution (`<()`) is a Bash extension, not available in standard shell.  Get `watch` to run your command in Bash instead:

```
watch -n 1 'bash -c "pr -m -t <(isig 4001+18) info1.txt"'
```